# How to add keep text with a HTML signature

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Seems that i can't add the text while adding the signature in the same code. Below you may see it:

```
 Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        With OutMail
             .to = email
             .cc = copy
             .subject = subject
             .body = body
             .HTMLbody = sig
```

That HTMLbody is deleting the body that i have 1 row up in the formula.

I have tryed to modify as i saw in other examples here, but nothing seems to work.Bellow you can see also the whole project.
Can you check and let me know were i have faild?

```
Sub send_mass_email()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim name, email, body, subject, copy, place, business As String
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim fsFile As Object
    Dim fso As Object
Dim fsFolder As Object
Dim strFolder As String
Dim sig As String
sig = ReadSignature("adi.htm")

    HTMLbody = ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("TextBox 1").Text
    
    i = 2
    'Loop down name column starting at row 2 column 1
    Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
        
        name = Split(Cells(i, 1).Value, " ")(0) 'extract first name
        email = Cells(i, 2).Value
        subject = Cells(i, 3).Value
        copy = Cells(i, 4).Value
        business = Cells(i, 5).Value
      
      answ = MsgBox("what it need to be attach " & Cells(i, 1) & " ?", vbYesNo + vbExclamation, "PSK Check")


If answ <> vbYes Then

      
      
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        With OutMail
             .to = email
             .cc = copy
             .subject = subject
             .HTMLbody = body
             .HTMLbody = sig
                          
             .display
            
    End With
  
 End If
 
 If answ = vbYes Then
 
       Set xFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    If xFileDlg.Show = -1 Then

        
        'replace place holders
        
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        With OutMail
             .to = email
             .cc = copy
             .subject = subject
             
            
             .HTMLbody = body & sig
             
             .display
             
            
        For Each xFileDlgItem In xFileDlg.SelectedItems
                .Attachments.Add xFileDlgItem
            Next xFileDlgItem
            

            
            '.Send
            
        End With
       End If
      
       
        'reset body text
        body = ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("TextBox 1").Text
  End If
  
        i = i + 1
 Loop
    
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
  
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing these two lines...

```
         .HTMLbody = body
         .HTMLbody = sig
```

with

```
         .HTMLbody = body & sig
```

By the way, if you want a line break between the body and signature, try the following instead...

```
         .HTMLbody = body & "<br>" & sig
```

Comment: It worked but now how i want. it put the text in one line.

Comment: The last piece of code I posted should put a line break between the body and signature.  Did you try it?

Comment: You're assigning the body and sig in two places, so you'll need to use `.HTMLbody = body & "<br>" & sig` for each one.

Comment: Hey, indeed it put a line between the text and sig but the text is just paste in one line like this comment. that's the issue..

Comment: Then you'll need to edit your text before assigning it to your variable `body` by adding  `<p>` tags.   For example "<p>This is the first paragraph...</p><p>This is the second paragraph...</p>".